# Camel File component: file not getting transferred on localdisk

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Camel and I am doing something very basic. Trying to move a file from one directory to another, no processing.

```
try{

   from("file:E:\\input").to("file:E:\\output");
}
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No exceptions are being captured and the file path is absolute. Can anybody help me figure out what might be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: try adding some logging in your route !

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out

from("file://E:/input/?delete=true").to("file://E:/outputdir")